# Why does the TDZ (Temporal Dead Zone) become ineffective in Vue <script setup>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

TDZ means that you cannot access a variable before it has been initialized. However, in Vue script setup sugar, it is possible to access variables before initialization. Why does this happen? Is it due to scope promotion?

[image]

I tried in plain js and setup function, message cannot be accessed before initialization

```html
<script setup>
  console.log(message)
  const message = "hello vue setup"
</script>
<template>
  <div class="app">
    App
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="less" scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Since script setup syntax isn't spec-compliant JS and not thoroughly documented, you need to rely on the actual behaviour to determine how it works. Here this means that const is transformed to var at some point. This depends on your setup because this transform depends on Babel and its config.

Comment: @mplungjan A browser cannot properly handle <script setup>

Comment: @mplungjan <script setup> is supposed to be interpreted differently from <script> as it's not spec-compliant JS but DSL. It should be transformed by Vue SFC loader and not executed directly in a browser